# Как программно перезагрузить телефон

Tags: java, android

Вроде бы и вопрос не редкий, но у меня никак не получается перезагрузить телефон имея рут. (вариант с кнопкой, естественно, не приемлем)

В Manifest напихал, всё что нашёл:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
```

1)  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("system/bin/su").write("reboot").getBytes();` ошибка - подчёркнуто write

2)

```
void shotdown() throws IOException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot -p"});}
```

при запуске метода - приложение вылетает.

3) Пробовал много вариантов через интенты - ничего.

Может уже есть нетрадиционные варианты? Ну, например, программно осуществить "звонок" на системный код, типа *#*#код#*#* или хоть уже с какими то костылями =) Неужели я уже не имею права перезагрузить свой телефон?

Comment: Если приложение вылетает, покажите логи

Comment: а нафига? это вам не винда

Comment: Наверное надо как-то через api перезагружать, а не через командную строку.

Comment: Попробуйте это https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#reboot(java.lang.String) (под андроид не пишу нашёл на бум)

Answer (score 6):

Требуемый пермишен не относится к вашему методу перезагрузки, так как ваш метод требует телефон рутом(с su).  Для перезагрузки телефона требуется пермишен, как и раньше, но использовать  метод PowerManager # reboot.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService (Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
pm.reboot (null);
```